# Page.GetRouteURL in WebForms outputs "length" querystring param

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, routes

I'm working in a webforms app that uses routing in .net 4. I've defined a very basic route in global.asax as follows:

```
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("myRouteName", "MyRoutePath", "~/RouteHandlers/MyHandler.aspx");
```

In the codebehind of one of my pages I'm using `GetRouteUrl` to generate a the URL for this named route as follows:

```
        Response.RedirectPermanent(GetRouteUrl("myRouteName"));
```

This doesn't produce the expected result of `http://sitename/MyRoutePath`. Instead it produces `http://sitename/MyRoutePath?length=15`

The length parameter doesn't seem to hurt but I've spent a lot of time making the URLs look nice so I don't want to see an extra parameter there. Any idea how to disable it?

Answer (score 17):

I encountered this very same issue with just one of my routes using Web Forms this morning and I've got around it by providing a 2nd argument to the GetRouteUrl method, passing in null (as this particular route didn't require any route parameters).

For example:

```
GetRouteUrl("name-of-my-route", null)
```

My Url is now clean and is not appended with ?length=15.

Hopefully this might help your situation too.

Comment: He should mark this as the correct answer because it worked for me.  Thanks so much - this was driving me crazy!!